# Python - importing fastai results in SyntaxError

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

I am trying to setup an ML model using fastai and have to do the following imports:

```
import fastai.models
import fastai.nlp
import fastai.dataset
```

However, it gives me the following error by the `fastai` imports.

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fastai.nlp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fastai/nlp.py", line 172
    if os.path.isdir(path): paths=glob(f'{path}/*.*')
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Apparently, the character `f` in `glob(f'{path}/*.*')` is causing the error. I fixed the error by removing `f`, but it seems that there are lots of these errors in the `fastai` library.

My current thought is that I am using an incorrect python version. Could anyone give me some pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Strings in the shape of:

```
f'{path}/*.*'
```

are called *f-strings* and were introduced in Python3.6.
That's why you get the `SyntaxError` - for versions lower than Python3.6 a `SyntaxError` will be raised, as this syntax just doesn't exist in lower versions.

So obviously *fast-ai* is programmed for Python3.6 or higher.

When you take a look at the [installation issues (you have to scroll down a bit)](https://pypi.org/project/fastai/),
you can see under **Is My System Supported?** the first point:

> **Python: You need to have python 3.6 or higher**

So I'm afraid updating your python is the easiest way to solve the problem!

---

*If you like to learn more about f-strings you can take a look here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/*

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I installed fastai on python 3.6.6 as well. It allows me to do `import fastai` but doesn't allow me to `import fastai.dataset`. It says the package `dataset` does not exist. However, I do need the module `dataset`.

Comment: @Fan I'm not sure, but I believe it changed to `fastai.datasets` - can you try that? So `import fastai.datasets` then.